# DataTable pagination next button is disabled

Tags: python, jquery, flask, datatable

I'm trying to use server side DataTable. The data is fetched from SQL using python in a Flask bootstrap project. The page size of my DataTable is 10 rows and the total number of rows in the SQL table is 16 (but can potentially grow really big). The first 10 rows shows up fine, but the 'Next' button (as well as 'Previous', 'First' and 'Last') in the DataTable is grayed out so I cannot select/click to get to page 2 etc. (see image here below, I've only pasted the footer as the data itself is ok and not the problem here). As you can see the DataTable displays the 10 rows, and the 'recordsTotal' value seem to have been accepted too. I'm sure that the solution is really simple, but just not able to spot it. I've been struggling with it for quite a while and I'm running out of ideas what to try next. Appreciate it if anybody has the possibility to give a helping hand.
:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

...
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="idTrackTable" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

...
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
...
```

**JQuery / Javascript:**

```
...
    function myDrawTrackTable() {
        if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#idTrackTable')) {
            myTrackTable = $('#idTrackTable').DataTable();
        }
        else {
            myTrackTable = $('#idTrackTable').DataTable({
                ajax: '/track_search',
                serverSide: true,
                pagination: true,
                pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
                //processing: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                columns: [
                    { orderable: false, searchable: false },
                    { orderable: false, searchable: false },
                    { data: 'id', orderable: false, searchable: false, title: "Id" },
                    { data: 'lat', orderable: true, searchable: true, title: "Lat" },
                    { data: 'lon', orderable: true, searchable: true, title: "Lon" },
                    { data: 'head', orderable: true, searchable: true, title: "Heading" },
                ],
            });
        }
    }
...
```

**The dict returned to JS from python:**

```
return {
    'data': liData,
    'recordsFiltered': iTotalFiltered,
    'recordsTotal': iRecordsTotal,
    'draw': request.args.get('draw', type=int),
}
```

The liData table only contains 10 rows (as I'm using the SQL LIMIT function to avoid potentially feeding large amount of data to the datatable).
iRecordsTotal = 16
iTotalFiltered = 10

Comment: A look at your screenshot says "showing 1 to 10 of 10" - so there *is* only one page - where would "next" go if it was enabled?  There's no page 2 (as confirmed as you only have `[1]` not `[1] [2]`)

Comment: Looks like you're using [tag:datatables] - is that correct?  (subtly different tag from [tag:datatable])

Comment: Review datatables returned data: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data  - looks like `iiTotalFiltered` should *also* be 16 as you're not filtering records - this and `recordsTotal` tells datatables the *total records* - quote: "*not just the number of records being returned for this page of data*"

Comment: Yes, you're right I'm using dataTables (though the javascript declaration is DataTable, so indeed subtle :-))

Comment: Ah, you're right, when I set the iiTotalFiltered to 16 it's working! Thanks! You saved my day :-)